# I would like to creating an output txt file with format as header is the same input txt and the below lines from dictionary result:

Tags: python

I have an input txt file like this:

```
MA_HS   ;   TOAN   ;    LY    ;  HOA    ;    SINH ;    VAN    ;    ANH    ;   SU      ;   DIA   
NVan_A  ;  7,8,9,8 ;  1,8,9,8 ; 3,8,9,8 ; 6,8,9,8 ; 4,6,7,6,8 ; 0,6,7,6,8 ; 3,6,7,6,8 ; 9,6,7,6,8       
NVan_B  ;  6,9,8,4 ;  7,8,9,8 ; 7,8,9,8 ; 7,8,9,8 ; 5,6,7,6,8 ; 5,6,7,6,8 ; 5,6,7,6,8 ; 9,7,6,4,10
```

I have some code to make the dictionary from a text file with the value of the dictionary being the average calculated from each element in the input txt:

```py
Dic = {
    'NVan_A': {
        'TOAN': 8.1, 'LY': 7.8, 'HOA': 7.9, 'SINH': 8.05, 'VAN': 8.0, 'ANH': 7.8, 'SU': 7.95, 'DIA': 8.25
     },
     'NVan_B': {
         'TOAN': 5.2, 'LY': 8.1, 'HOA': 8.1, 'SINH': 8.1, 'VAN': 8.05, 'ANH': 8.05, 'SU': 8.05, 'DIA': 6.65
     }
}
```

I would like to create an output text file with the same header as the input text and the below lines from the dictionary result:

```
MA_HS   ; TOAN ; LY  ; HOA ; SINH ;  VAN  ; ANH  ; SU ; DIA  
NVan_A  ;  8.1 ; 7.8 ; 7.9 ; 8.05 ;  8.0  ; 7.8  ;7.95; 8.25        
NVan_B  ;  5.2 ; 8.1 ; 8.1 ; 8.05 ;  8.05 ; 8.05 ;8.05; 6.65
```

Could you please help me to solve this one?

Comment: Please show the code you have developed so far and describe what trouble you have with implementing your solution.

Answer (score -1):

Below code is not tested, just shows a simple way to solve the problem

```
# Store input headers as a list
columns = ['MA_HS', 'TOAN', 'LY', 'HOA', 'SINH', 'VAN', 'ANH', 'SU', 'DIA']    

row_keys = Dic.keys()
for a_row in row_keys:
    buf = f'{a_row}'
    sub_dict = Dic[a_row]
    for a_col in columns:
        buf += f' ; {sub_dict[a_col]}'
    output.write(buf, '\n')
```

Maybe there are many other elegant ways.

Comment: Following your instruction, I made code and print step by step, but look like the last code has an errror, I get warning like that:

Comment: Header ['MA_HS', 'TOAN', 'LY', 'HOA', 'SINH', 'VAN', 'ANH', 'SU', 'DIA']


row_keys: dict_keys(['NVan_A', 'NVan_B'])
buf:  NVan_A
sub_dict:  {'TOAN': 8.1, 'LY': 7.8, 'HOA': 7.9, 'SINH': 8.05, 'VAN': 8.0, 'ANH': 7.8, 'SU': 7.95, 'DIA': 8.25}
buf:  NVan_B
sub_dict:  {'TOAN': 5.2, 'LY': 8.1, 'HOA': 8.1, 'SINH': 8.1, 'VAN': 8.05, 'ANH': 8.05, 'SU': 8.05, 'DIA': 6.65}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL 7440\Desktop\workingon\gpa.py", line 74, in <module>
    buf += f'; {sub_dict[a_col]}'
KeyError: 'MA_HS'

Comment: Please remove the 'MA_HS' from the list 'columns'